# How to group by date leaving hour?

Tags: c#

So I have a list of matches which have a property called `Schedule`, this property is a `DateTime` and can contains the following values:

```
id | Schedule
 1    2018-08-11 14:00 
 2    2018-08-11 20:00
 3    2018-08-12 15:00
```

now I want group all the date available in this list, so I tried:

```
var dates = matches.GroupBy(c => c.Schedule);
```

the problem is that I get all the dates, but I should get as result: `1, 3`, because the date `1 and 2` are equal (only the hour change and this shouldn't matter).

Comment: You're grouping by a `DateTime`, which will create one group for every unique Date **and time**. Try `.GroupBy(c => c.Schedule.Date)`.

Comment: Just group by c.Schedule.Hour

Comment: thanks really forgot to do this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using property `Date`

```
var dates = matches.GroupBy(c => c.Schedule.Date);
```